# Php laravel how to use blade in echo

Tags: php, html, laravel

in my echo statement like this

```
echo "<a href='../edit/$tmpd'><img src='/images/pjdict/edit.png' width='42' height='42' style='margin-right:20px'  data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'></a>";
```

in link attribute i need to use {{ URL::to('index/edit/$tmpd') }}

because if i same. it more confuse to link from different page.

how can i edit my code.

Comment: `{{ 'test' }}` <- this means `echo 'test';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you get the point here

```
<a href="{{ url('edit', $tmpd) }}"><img src='/images/pjdict/edit.png' width='42' height='42' style='margin-right:20px'  data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'></a>
```